# CSS: Using flexbox for structure content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a layout like below image. It includes:

- A left part
- A right part
- A title stretch whole row

[image]

I can do as structure html like this and using some layout such as Flexbox, div positioning ...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="status">
    <div class="left">12/05/2015</div>
    <div class="right>Adventure Story</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">A long story about the Atlantic</div>
</div>
```

I just learn Flexbox and I want to simplify to this html (no wrapper against the first row)

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">12/05/2015</div>
      <div class="right>Adventure Story</div>
      <div class="title">A long story about the Atlantic</div>
</div>
```

Can I use Flexbox for above html structure. If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* to avoid overflow and force title going to new line */
}

.left,
.right {
  flex: 0 0 50%; /*each element will take 50% of the width */
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.title {
  flex: 0 0 100%; /*this element will take 100% of the width*/
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">12/05/2015</div>
  <div class="right">Adventure Story</div>
  <div class="title">A long story about the Atlantic</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap` on flex-container and `flex: 0 0 100%` on `title` element so that it goes to new row and `margin-left: auto` on second element in order to position it to the right side.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.title {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">12/05/2015</div>
  <div class="right">Adventure Story</div>
  <div class="title">A long story about the Atlantic</div>
</div>
```